# How to disable notification about extension updates in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010 you get automatic notifications about extension updates. I don't want to be notified of that. Is there a way to disable that feature?

Comment: They come from the productivity power tools, so you could uninstall that if it really bothers you.  Not to be too glib, but you could also just install updates to get the notification to go away (unless you have some extensions installed that get updates all the time).

Comment: I don't want to install updates for some extensions because that means more than just extension. I'm using RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX and there's an extension related to that called Telerik WebUI VSExtensions which follows the version of the control package.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Extension Manager
and uncheck "Automatically check for updates to installed extensions".

Answer (score 2):

I think it will depend on each individual extension's setting. However, some extensions might not have the option for you to disable auto updates.

For instance, if you want to disable VSCommands 2010 extension auto updates, you can go to Tools -> Options -> VSCommands 2010 -> Other Settings -> uncheck Automatically check for updates to installed extensions.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict Visual Studio's access to the Internet by using the built-in Windows firewall.

Comment: I don't know who down-voted this. It actually sounds like a good idea. I might try it.

Comment: It works and I don't see any side effects. Debugging an ASP.NET application with the built in web server works fine.

Comment: Well, I've hit an issue now. The dataset designer can't connect to the SQL Server database located on another machine in the LAN. I guess I could perhaps edit the firewall rule so it only blocks port 80.